# Cannot start MongoDB service as I bind a specified IP

Tags: mongodb

My current MongoDB configuration,

```
options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.0.204", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid", timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
```

Here's the issue I am having,

```
2018-02-02T19:16:32.017+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
2018-02-02T19:16:32.017+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-02-02T19:16:32.017+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

Answer (score 1):

First solution on *nix:
You could  bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 and use a firewall to block all incoming connections to port 27017, unless coming from local ip adress.
Second solution

Restart mongo:

```
> service mongod restart
```

Go to to /var/logs/mongodb and give the information from logs.

Let try to test mongo, is it running localy with default options?

```
> service mongod status
```

That tells you the status of mongo.
If it disactive, go to logs, in my case it /var/logs/mongodb
get info from log.

Then, lets try to start mongo without remote IP option.
goto /etc/mongod.conf
and set up option only on local ip, ***bindIp 127.0.0.1***
then

> service mongod restart

and

> service mongod status

Is it running? If everything is fine, You need determine what your's local lan ip addres.

in my case it was command, other commands [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/145017)

> LANG=c ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet addr" |awk '{ if ( $1 == "inet" ) {
>   print $2 } else if ( $2 == "Link" ) { printf "%s:" ,$1 } }' |awk -F:
>   '{ print $1 ": " $3 }'

After that add it ip addres to mongo conf with comma separated option.
like:
bindIp 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.66

than save config and simply restart mongo

> service mongod restart

Comment: Must the bindIp be the mongod's server ip?If it is,Why the setting of bindIp "0.0.0.0"  start successfully.Because  "0.0.0.0" means any ips,i want to bind a ip which is not install mongodb and this does not works

Answer (score -1):

The bind_ip is for “local interface only”, put 192.168.162.129 (Server A private ip) is enough for clients (like Server B) on the same LAN to access.

Use these step it will work:

1. sudo vim /etc/mongodb.conf
2. bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 172.31.29.201
3. Note that 172.31.29.201 is private IP not public IP. Please use private IP here
4. sudo service mongodb restart
5. sudo service mongodb status - To check mongodb services are running or not
6. Enjoy